# How to obtain list of all available topics [python]

Tags: rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In my gazebo model I have 9 differential drive vehicles.
When I execute `rostopic list` i  get

```
/bot_0/cmd_vel
/bot_0/odom
/bot_1/cmd_vel
/bot_1/odom
/bot_2/cmd_vel
/bot_2/odom
/bot_3/cmd_vel
/bot_3/odom
/bot_4/cmd_vel
/bot_4/odom
/bot_5/cmd_vel
/bot_5/odom
/bot_6/cmd_vel
/bot_6/odom
/bot_7/cmd_vel
/bot_7/odom
/bot_8/cmd_vel
/bot_8/odom
/clock
/gazebo/link_states
...    and so on
```

I wish to find out all the *odom* topics in python script and subscribe to **all** of them using the [message_filter](http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters)

However, I am not being able to find/locate the `getTopics()` function as is mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26785675)  Kindly let me know what package do I import to get the **getTopics()** function working.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256251/how-to-obtain-list-of-all-available-topics-%5Bpython%5D/) by [vvyogi](https://answers.ros.org/users/29579/vvyogi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2017-03-06

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `getTopics` function is C++ only. The equivalent function in Python is [get_published_topics](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/rospy/html/rospy.client-module.html#get_published_topics).

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2017-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Felix Widmaier](https://answers.ros.org/users/28762/felix-widmaier/) on 2018-02-09**:
Note that this only gives topics that are advertised while `rostopic list` also shows topics that are only subscribed to by some node.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Adapted this out of https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/noetic-devel/tools/rostopic/src/rostopic/__init__.py#L1223-L1231 (maybe if I looked a little more there's a more convenient function and I wouldn't need to populate a dict)

```
import rosgraph
import rostopic
...

# not sure if any better or different that master=None
master = rosgraph.Master('/rostopic')
pubs, subs = rostopic.get_topic_list(master=master)
topic_data = {}
print(f"subs {len(subs)}")
for topic in pubs:
    name = topic[0]
    if name not in topic_data:
        topic_data[name] = {}
        topic_data[name]['type'] = topic[1]
    topic_data[name]['publishers'] = topic[2]
print(f"subs {len(pubs)}")
for topic in subs:
    name = topic[0]
    if name not in topic_data:
        topic_data[name] = {}
        topic_data[name]['type'] = topic[1]
    topic_data[name]['subscribers'] = topic[2]

for topic_name in sorted(topic_data.keys()):
    print(topic_name)
```

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2022-01-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1